# Django Template does not exist: Same code and software in different machine

Tags: python, windows, django-templates

I am finding a ***TemplateDoesNotExist at/*** error when running a Django project in local host using python manage.py runserver). The django app works perfectly in my development machine (Windows 10). The error is in the deployment server machine (Windows Server 2016).

Any idea of what can be wrong having **same Project code, Django and Python** versions?

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader is not being called. Any reason this may happen? I have 'DIRS' not empty. This loader is enabled by default according to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader

Answer (score 0):

Changed Python version from **Python 3.6.7** to **Python 3.6.8** and it worked OK!